# Is a /proc mount necessary in /etc/fstab?

Tags: configuration, fstab, proc

[This ZFS guide](https://github.com/dajhorn/pkg-zfs/wiki/HOWTO-install-Ubuntu-to-a-Native-ZFS-Root-Filesystem) claims:

> The Ubuntu desktop installer may add `dev`, `proc`, `sys`, or `tmp` lines to the `/etc/fstab` file, but such entries are not strictly necessary for a modern system. Add them now if you want them.

How true is this? My Ubuntu 12.04 installation contains an explicit `/proc` mount. If it's unnecessary, why does Ubuntu include it?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The claimed statement is generally true:

> It is not necessary to list `/proc` and `/sys` in the fstab unless some special options are needed. The boot system will always mount them. [(Debian Wiki)](http://wiki.debian.org/fstab)

- The only reason Debian (and by extension, Ubuntu) includes it is as a forgotten remnant of the bad old days when it used to be necessary.
- [This behavior is a bug in the installer package `partman-target`](http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=674481) and was recently fixed in Debian Testing *(wheezy)* on June 15, 2012.
- So, you can expect Ubuntu to "fix" this in 12.10...

Comment: 14.04 does not contain it anymore.